# Is it possible to get speed of wifi of iPhone device programmatically

Tags: iphone, network-programming, wifi

Is it possible to find out the speed of internet connectivity via wifi or 3G connection in iPhone or iPad device. We can find the device connected to 3G or wifi programmatically that I know and already implemented in the project. Now I need to display the information about the internet speed of the wifi as well as 3G connection of iPhone device depend upon the connection it uses.

Can anyone help me to find out solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to download/upload an file to get the speed. And you can display the speed after that, by knowing the size of the file and the amount of time that took to download/upload the file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Here we need to get the speed for the statical purpose only. But the approach you suggested is something that we need to wait for download/upload and then only we can know the answer. If you have any other solution please let me know.